# centeredScaling is not working with slider control

Tags: jquery, slider, fabricjs, fabricjs2

centeredScaling is not working with slider control.

It works when we scale object manually by using object's corner.

I want scale object using slider control in my project.

Comment: Here I made fiddle for it.
https://jsfiddle.net/AppleDev/gpj20mzh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no centered scaling if not for the built in mouse inteaction.
When you scale by code, you should take care of object position manually.

Here is how you do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('can');
canvas.set({
  fireRightClick: true,
  stopContextMenu: true,
  preserveObjectStacking: true,
    stateful: false,
  centeredScaling: false,
  
 });
  
var initText = new fabric.Text("Good Morning", {
    left: 170,
    top: 120,
    fill: '#000',
    fontSize: 40,
    textAlign: 'center',
    centeredScaling: true,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    hasRotatingPoint: false,
    minScaleLimit:0.4,
    flipX: false,
    flipY: false,
    padding: 10,
    isClick: true,
   });
   
   initText.setControlsVisibility({
    mt: false,
    mb: false,
    ml: false,
    mr: false,
    tr: true,
    tl: true,
    br: true,
    bl: true
   });
   initText.hasRotatingPoint = false;
      canvas.add(initText).bringToFront(initText).renderAll();
   initText.center();
   initText.setCoords();
      

$("#slider").slider({
  min: 0.3,
  max: 5,
  step:0.1,
  animate: "fast",
  change: function( event, ui ) {
   var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
   if (obj) {  
    //if(activeObject.type === "text"){
     objscale = obj.scaleX;
     if(obj.scaleX == obj.scaleY){
      objscale = obj.scaleX;
     } 
   }
   
  },
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
   var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
   if (obj) {  
     var slider_scale = $(this).slider("value");
     objscale = slider_scale;
     
     if(objscale != "" && objscale > 0){
            var center = obj.getCenterPoint();
      obj.scale(parseFloat(objscale));
            obj.setPositionByOrigin(center, 'center', 'center');
      //obj.center().setCoords();
      canvas.requestRenderAll();
     }  
   }
   
  },
 });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#can {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="can" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
<br><br>
 <div class="text-size" style="text-align:center;">
   <div id="slider"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok. Understand.. I have to maintain the position of the object when I scale the objevt every time.

Comment: fabricJS does same internally for each scaling operation